# Combine ViewComponents in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to combine multiple different ViewComponents from a controller. The ActionResult of all combined viewcomponents will be rendered to the browser.
This is based on an article which does this with PartialViews and updates the PartialViews with ajax. That article is based on previous version of MVC. For more info see: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp.net-mvc/

After many hours I came to the following code example. But the problem is that it works only for the first viewComponent. When I change the order of viewcomponents it still renders the first one. So it doesn't seem to have anything with my viewcomponents. Always at second loop it ends at "vc.ExecuteResultAsync(context);" with no errors. So rendering the first one is always successful.

By the way I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise with Beta7 of MVC6 and all other dependencies.

Please help!

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Dashboard()
    {
        // Combine multiple viewcomponents
        return new MultipleViewResult(
            ViewComponent(typeof(OrdersViewComponent))
            , ViewComponent(typeof(AccountsViewComponent))
            );
    }

    public class MultipleViewResult : ActionResult
    {
    public const string ChunkSeparator = "---|||---";
    public IList<ViewComponentResult> ViewComponentResults { get; private set; }
    public MultipleViewResult(params ViewComponentResult[] views)
    {
        if (ViewComponentResults == null)
        {
            ViewComponentResults = new List<ViewComponentResult>();
        }

        foreach (var v in views)
            ViewComponentResults.Add(v);
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        byte[] chunkSeparatorBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ChunkSeparator);
        var total = ViewComponentResults.Count;
        for (var index = 0; index < total; index++)
        {
            var vc = ViewComponentResults[index];

            // No matter which viewcomponent, this line works only with the first viewcomponent.
            await vc.ExecuteResultAsync(context);

            if (index < total - 1)
            {
                await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(chunkSeparatorBytes, 0, chunkSeparatorBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be overwriting response body each time you do ExecuteResultAsync. Not sure, though. Check this link to see what's happening behind the scenes: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/e91ce4560f46b0bbcd1e5e3b4430e2291b408c54?diff=unified#diff-707effa79d34b01ef21df4ecf89e9497R66

Answer (score 0):

This fails because the first `vc.ExecuteResultAsync(context)` will set the `ContentType` property and **flush** the response. Any succeeding call to  `vc.ExecuteResultAsync(context)` will also try to set the `ContentType` property but will fail because the response has already been streamed back to the client.

I can't think of any better workaround other than creating your own instance of `HttpContext` that would allow you write to the ContentType property even if part of the response has already been sent back but this is messy.

If you believe this is a bug (I personally think it is because the ViewComponentResult should check if the response has already been sent before setting the ContentType), then you can always [submit a bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues).

Comment: After first time the context.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted goes from "false" to "true". I think that means that response is flushed and the ContentType cannot be set anymore. Probably because of "HasStarted" property.

Comment: You are correct. That property should be checked before setting the ContentType. I see you (or someone) have filed a [bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3111) already.